# Supported 'type' for SingleValueExtendedProperty ids?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble pulling back a `SingleValueExtendedProperties` of type `Float`. In the Graph Explorer, the specific query I'm running is:
[`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'Float {00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Id 0x00008102')`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'Float%20%7B00062003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046%7D%20Id%200x00008102')&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com) (click to try it)

The extended property I'm trying to get is [PidLidPercentComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203495(v=exchg.80).aspx).

I've been able to pull back SingleValueExtendedProperies of type `Binary`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, `SystemTime`, and `String`.

Unfortunately I can't seem to find an exhaustive list of supported types. I tried out the names in [MapiPropertyType enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.mapipropertytype(v=exchg.80).aspx) to no avail.

1. Is that the right list, or is just a subset of supported type names?
2. If `float` is not supported, will it ever be?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Including some sample code for example is important so someone in the community can replicate your issue and help diagnose what is going on.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft, I just edited it and added the specific example.

Comment: If memory serves, `PidLidPercentComplete` is a property of a Task. In order to return that I believe you'd need to use the older Outlook API which supports [Extended Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#ExtendedPropertyIdFormats) of a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/task-rest-operations) object.